# Google Script Error .setFormula with REGEXREPLACE

Tags: google-apps-script, regexp-replace

I am trying to replace hyphens in phone numbers utilizing a Google Script.

Here is what I have:

```
function FillFormulas() {   

var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('HubSpotSheet');   

var lastRow = spreadsheet.getLastRow();   

spreadsheet.getRange("F2").setFormula("=iferror(REGEXREPLACE(D2,"[[:punct:]]", ""),D2)");   
var fillDownRange = spreadsheet.getRange(2,6,(lastRow-1));   spreadsheet.getRange("F2").copyTo(fillDownRange); 

}
```

However, I am getting an error - How do I write the formula in a way where I will not get an error?

I tried different variations of the formula, but Google Scripts did not accept the other variations either.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you need double quotes `"` within the formula so you can not start and end the formula with double quotes.  Instead use single quotes `'`

Replace

```
spreadsheet.getRange("F2").setFormula("=iferror(REGEXREPLACE(D2,"[[:punct:]]", ""),D2)");
```

With

```
spreadsheet.getRange("F2").setFormula('=iferror(REGEXREPLACE(D2,"[[:punct:]]", ""),D2)');
```

Comment: If this answers your question then mark this as the answer so others with similar issues can find a solution.